# How to properly test interpolated string from yaml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, yaml, capybara

I have rspec/capybara test that is testing for the expectation of a string, but the test is replacing the variable.

The sting in the yaml:

```
title: Sold %{product}
```

Expectation in test:

```
expect(page).to have_text(t("sell_successes.show.title"))
```

Result:

```
expected to find text "Sold %{product}" in blah blah
```

When is should be looking for:

```
expected to find text "Sold shoes" in blah blah
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yaml contains a string template, so you need to provide it with the value to place into the template

```
expect(page).to have_text(t("sell_successes.show.title") % { product: 'shoes' })
```